# How can I disallow normal users on Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 (multi user NIS setup) from shutting down the system?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, gdm

In the past, I was able to set "SystemMenu=false" in gdm.conf, to prevent normal users from being able to shut down the system.

In ubuntu 10.04, this does not work.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

With gdm 2.30 in a default Ubuntu configuration, the shutdown menu is shown by the [simple greeter](http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#greeterconfiguration) and can be turned off by adding the following line in `/var/lib/gdm/.gconf/apps/gdm/simple-greeter/%gconf.xml`:

```
<entry name="disable_restart_buttons" type="bool" value="true"/>
```